# Issue installing Torch & Torchvision

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm on MacOS (Ventura 13.1) and trying to install PyTorch on Python version 3.11.1

I ran the following command per the PyTorch website via the terminal

```
pip3 install torch torchvision
```

but getting the following error when running

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

After much troubleshooting, it's not clear what could be wrong here.

I expected the installation to take place but getting this error instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Python you are using is not compatible with PyTorch. PyTorch supports Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10. It is possible that PyTorch does not yet support Python 3.11.

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/86566)

Comment: Thanks. But the website mentions only 3.7-3.9 is it outdated?

Currently, PyTorch on Windows only supports Python 3.7-3.9; Python 2.x is not supported.

https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-python:~:text=Currently%2C%20PyTorch%20on%20Windows%20only%20supports%20Python%203.7%2D3.9%3B%20Python%202.x%20is%20not%20supported.